# Playframework : Deploy website

Tags: web-deployment, playframework-2.2, web-deployment-project

So, I have completed developing a website using Play 2.2 framework. I have a basic question of `How to deploy the play application?` I have followed the steps given in [Play Production mode](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist) and generated files in `target/universal/stage/bin` and all related files using `[project]$ dist` command. Now, What I have to do with the files that are generated ? How can I put this live? Please specify steps require to deploy this application or a helpful article.

I am a newbie so this question may be too simple to ask.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

- send the unziped files to server
- find `start` and make it executable : `chmod +x start`
- start the application on port 80 like `./start -Dhttp.port=80` (don't forget to use `nohup`, otherwise application will terminate, when you'll close SSH session)

That's all

Tip for easier maintenance you can use for an instance Jenkins - or some other CI system - with `rsync` command you can prepare one-click task for redeploying app even at distant location.

If you need to run more than 1 application at port 80 on the same machine use some lightweight HTTP server for reverse proxy and/or load balancing, i.e. *nginx* works perfect.